# How to change default package installation location of pip in ubuntu?

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.7

I have pip3 installed on my ubuntu machine. I also have python3.5 and python3.7 installed. When I install a package using pip3 it is getting installed in python3.5 packages folder, so i'm unable to use that package in python3.7. How do i resolve this?

Comment: The _best_ solution is to use virtual environments. Don't install "into python3.5" or "into python3.7", but rather "into the virtualenv for some application".

Answer (score 1):

you can assign the python version like this:

```py
python3.5 -m pip install xxx
or
python3.7 -m pip install xxx
```

other way use virtualenv, like pipenv, poetry etc.

Answer (score 0):

Better to create virtual environment and install packages into that

```
python3.6 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
python3.8 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

Activate your virtual environment

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

Install package using pip

```
pip install package-name
```

now the package will be install in particular python version which you previously used to create virtual environment